# User Pages Facebook Graph API Call Error: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user"

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I am making a Facebook Graph API call to return the user accounts that are linked to my facebook page. However, when making this call (https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/me/accounts) it returns this:

Response:
{
"error": {
"message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 2500,
"fbtrace_id": "Aih7dZduWPVznNHi9VK4JOZ"
}
}

```
def getUserPages(params) :

    url = params['endpoint_base'] + 'me/accounts'

    return makeAPICall(url, params['access_token'], params['debug'])

params = getCreds()
params['debug'] = 'yes'
response = getUserPages(params)
```

```
def makeAPICall( url, endpointParams, debug = 'no' ) : 
    data = requests.get( url, endpointParams )

    response = dict()
    response['url'] = url
    response['endpoint_params'] = endpointParams
    response['endpoint_params_pretty'] = json.dumps( endpointParams, indent = 4)
    response['json_data'] = json.loads( data.content )
    response['json_data_pretty'] = json.dumps( response['json_data'], indent = 4)

    if ('yes' == debug) :
        displayAPICallData(response)

    return response
```

This is the code I ran to make the call. Params['access_token'] is a long-lived user access token that I was able to get from the Graph API which doesn't expire until 2024-01-17 09:59:56. getCreds() just returns all the necessary parameters needed to make the API Call with my app. I expected to get a list of all of the social media accounts that are linked to my facebook account.